# how should I state this?

Tags: limits

So we have a piecewise function:

I've show it is continuous at x=0 and now I am trying to express in mathematical terms (if possible) that the derivative does not exist because:

The derivative is defined as the limit: $$f'(x)=\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}\tag{1}$$ Thus, for x = 0; $f'(0)=\frac{f(\Delta x)-f(0)}{\Delta x}$

Since, for any $\Delta x$ we choose so that $f'(0)$ is rational there exists a smaller $\Delta x$ such that $f'(0)$ is irrational, and vice versa, it follows that as $\Delta x$ tends to 0, $f'(0)=1$ or $f'(0)=0$. The limit/derivative is therefore not defined.

I feel like there is a better way to express this. I don't want to prove it just express it more mathematically.

Also, $
f(x)=\begin{cases}
 x, \,   \text{ if } x \text{ is rational }\\
 0, \, \text{ if } x \text{ is irrational }
\end{cases}
$

Comment: Your post would be easier to follow if you put the definition of $f$ at the beginning, not the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the following, $$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(\Delta x) }{\Delta x}$$

For rational $\Delta x$ we get $$\frac{f(\Delta x) }{\Delta x}=1$$

And for irrational $\Delta x$ we get $$\frac{f(\Delta x) }{\Delta x}=0$$

Thus the limit does not exist.

Intuitively you have two different slopes at $x=0$ which is not good.

Comment: That is exactly what I said but condensed in a much more effective form. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Yes, it is the same argument as you have made in your statement.

Comment: One point of improvement. It should be for rational $\Delta x $ we get $f(\Delta x)/\Delta x = 1$ and for the other one it should be 0. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks for correction. I edited my answer.